# Does fixed array from derived extend the fixed array from base?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, layout, structure

Assuming I have the following:

```
struct A
{
    unsigned x,y;
    char b[4];
};

template <unsigned N> struct B : public A
{
    static constexpr unsigned L = N + sizeof(A::b);
    char e[N];
};
```

Should I assume that the static array from B will be appended to the static array from A? Such that I could treat the array from `A` as having a size that would also include the array from `B`.

For example, the following would output `than 4 bytes`:

```
using T = B<60>;

T o;

snprintf(o.b, T::L, "more than 4 bytes");

puts(o.e);
```

Which it does. But I'm not an expert in how a more complex compiler actually deals with deciding the layout the structures and/or in what order it might arrange those types in memory. Depending on the requested optimizations.

Which is why I'm asking if this might have unexpected results. And if so, under what circumstances. And what should I expect?

Leaving aside the warnings given by the compiler for "*out of range access*" (*if any*).

Also, this is not the actual use case. But rather an example to better describe my question.

Comment: No, you cannot assume any such thing.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `A::b` and `B::e` will be contiguous in memory. The compiler may add padding between `A` and `B`, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Behavior is undefined by C++ standard (and not just because of alignment). However on mainstream compilers IF you add `__attribute__((packed))` to both structures (packed is gcc thing, but others have analogs), then it should work. Your code will depend on compiler implementation details though, you'll need static assertion to safeguard against breakage:

```
// dummy class B_ used in static assertion in B since the value
// of offsetof(B,e) is yet undefined at that point
template <unsigned N> struct B_ : public A
{
    char e[sizeof(A::b) + N];
} __attribute__((packed));

template <unsigned N> struct B : public A
{
    STATIC_ASSERT(OFFSETOF(B_, A::b) + sizeof(A::b) == OFFSETOF(B_::e));
    char e[sizeof(A::b) + N];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

But it's all so ugly. I recommend asking question closer to you actual code, likely there are easier ways to accomplish what you want.